# Skip multiple examples in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, rspec3

Does anyone know a way to skip multiple examples within a group, without duplicating the skip statement between them?

For example, given this test:

```rb
describe 'some feature' do
  it 'should do something' do
    ...
  end

  it 'should do something else too' do
    ...
  end
end
```

a `skip` doesn't work if placed before the first example, like so:

```rb
describe 'some feature' do
  skip 'I would like to skip both with one statement'

  it 'should do something' do
    ...
  end

  it 'should do something else too' do
    ...
  end
end
```

An ideal solution would allow me to skip at any level of the example structure (`describe`/`feature`, `context`, and `scenario`/`it`) and would skip all children of that level of the hierarchy.

In other words, would allow me to do:

```rb
describe 'some feature' do
  it 'should do something' do
    ...
  end

  it 'should do something else too' do
    skip 'just one of these for now'
    ...
  end
end
```

AND

```rb
describe 'some feature' do
  skip 'everything within this describe block'

  it 'should do something' do
    ...
  end

  it 'should do something else too' do
    ...
  end
end
```

AS WELL AS

```rb
describe 'some feature' do
  context 'such and such' do
    skip 'just this context'

    it 'should do something' do
      ...
    end

    it 'should do something else too' do
      ...
    end

  it 'but do not skip this one' do
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-8/docs/pending-and-skipped-examples/skip-examples#skipping-using-metadata), you can use metadata to skip a context.

```rb
describe 'some feature', :skip do
  it 'should do something' do
    # This example is skipped
  end

  it 'should do something else too' do
    # This example is skipped as well
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmmm. Specifically, I was looking for a way to pass the reason for the skip as an argument, as in the examples I posted in the question details; it seems like because the option to use a tag exists, the other use case isn't covered. Thank you for your answer.